# How can I revive wilted water basil plants?

Tags: diagnosis, wilt, basil

I bought these basil plants from the store. They looked a little droopy and wilting. They came with several bunches and they were half off and discounted because they've been there in the store so long.

The instructions on the bag indicated to put in a cup of water a little past the root. We did that and they seemed near their death after doing so. Are there any remedies to revive them?

The plant currently sits indoors in one of my very large beer mug. By my kitchen sink away from the cat.

Comment: @Chris, if the basil plants are more than just seedlings, get them out in sunshine (Basil (nearly all herbs love sunshine), maybe not full on midday sunshine initially, but nevertheless give them some sunshine each day to get them hardened off...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be past the possibility of resuscitation, but I would recommend sunlight. Assuming you're in Texas perhaps not direct sun right now, but more than it would be getting inside.

You also could try pulling off leaves which are already so wilted they're not going to stay or little ones that don't have a large enough surface area to catch much light. This means you're maximising the energy from sunlight that's going to the remainder of the plant, and not letting any go to waste on the lost-cause leaves.

Comment: Awesome. Actually i did end up doing that and it seems like the plant is doing better but with less leaves.

Answer (score 5):

I'd try an organic supplement spray like Sea Magic.  I've had great success with vegetable, fruit, herb, and houseplants that start to look wilted to get them to perk up again.  It is used to help encourage stronger growth and more production and also helps prohibit leaf decay while stimulating foliage production too.  Sea Kelp or Fish Fertilizer would probably be an option worth trying to perhaps more readily available in garden centers.